# passing MVC3 model to Javascript block as JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass my MVC3 model into a script block on the client. Here's my approach (Razor view):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = @( Json.Encode(Model) );
</script>
```

Here "Model" is just an array of strings.  This renders almost correctly, but the encoding is funny:

```
var items = [&quot;item1&quot;,&quot;item2&quot;,&quot;item3];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @ sign html encodes your output if its not an MvcString - so use Html.Raw

```
var items = @Html.Raw( Json.Encode(Model) );
```